# Saving form items to other list

Tags: infopath, custom-list, list-form

Is there any way where I can store my form items to another list? like in InfoPath maybe through data connection?

Comment: Are you asking about temporary storage of items?

Comment: Yes kind of temporary only.

Comment: No, you can not store temporary data to the list directly.it can't be used like data connection.